# Convergence of an infinite product

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

For which $a \in \mathbb{R^+}$ does the sequence $$\gamma_n=(1+a)(1+2a^2)\cdots(1+na^n)$$ converge? Give a brief explanation.

---

**My attempt**:

Is easy to see that

- $a=0 \implies \gamma_n \equiv1$;
- $a \ge 1 \implies$ $\gamma_n$ diverges.

Convergence: if $0<a<1$, $\gamma_n$ converges $\iff$ $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+ka^k)$ converges.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \ln(1+ka^k) \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty ka^k=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}<+\infty$$ so $\gamma_n(a)$ converges in $[0,1) \space \blacksquare$

---

Is the solution correct? If yes, Is there a briefer explanation?

Comment: Correct and straight to the point, hard to write a shorter proof.

Comment: This looks great.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, is an honour, I just found this exercise from a link to Tolaso J. Kos in your course notes “Superior Mathematics from an Elementary point of view”

Comment: I really *am* honoured, thank you.

Comment: Not terribly useful or relevant, but if $A(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_nx^n$ we have $[axA(ax)]' = \frac{(1-x)A(x) - 1}{x}$.

Comment: Ok. To be very fussy, I would say you should append "$0<$" to the far left of your last display-line. ....BTW if $x_n\geq 0$ then $\prod_n(1+x_n)$ converges iff  $\sum_n x_n$ converges. And if $0\leq y_n<1$ then $\prod_n(1-y_n)>0$ iff $\sum_ny_n$ converges.